# Números e plural

Tags: números, número-gramatical

Existe alguma regra geral para quando dizer "X ponto" ou "X ponto**s**" quando X < 2?

Por exemplo, se alguém faz uma pontuação de X = 0.5 em um jogo, pode-se dizer tanto que a pessoa fez "meio ponto" quanto "zero ponto cinco ponto(s?)". Nesse último caso, o plural é necessário, opcional ou incorreto?

Tenho a mesma dúvida para X = 0, 0.1, 1.1 e 1.5.

---

(OBS.: Sei que o padrão na língua portuguesa é usar "," como separador decimal, mas estou usando "." porque acho mais fácil de ler.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Em português de Portugal, usa-se o plural para qualquer número excepto 1.

Isso inclui o 0, números decimais no intervalo [0, 1) e no intervalo (1, 2].

Exemplos:

> Eu coloquei 0 **questões** durante a entrevista.
>
> Hoje, estão zero **graus** celsius.
>
> Este ano, o governo gastou 1.6 **milhões** em educação.
>
> Ontem andei 0.5 **quilómetros**.

No entanto, no português do Brasil, é preferido o uso do singular ([segundo a minha pesquisa](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1881)):

> No Brasil, tal uso é mais raro, sendo geralmente considerado agramatical e preterido em favor do singular (ex.: *zero grau*, *zero ponto*, *à zero hora*, etc.), como aliás é aconselhado no Manual de Redação e Estilo de O Estado de S. Paulo (3ª ed., S. Paulo, O Estado de S. Paulo, 1997 p. 313), de Eduardo Martins, e exemplificado no verbete zero do Dicionário Houaiss (Rio de Janeiro, Objetiva, 2001).
>
> Assim sendo, na norma portuguesa, a leitura mais consensual de 0,25 mol parece ser *zero vírgula vinte e cinco moles* e a de 1,2 l *um vírgula dois litros*, enquanto na norma brasileira parece ser *zero vírgula vinte e cinco mol* e *um vírgula dois litro*, respectivamente.

Comment: Ótima resposta, bastante abrangente. Obrigado! :)

Comment: Então, em Portugal, seria plural mesmo quando o número termina em 1? No caso, 0,1 milhões?

Comment: @geekley sim, é isso.