# Uso do plural ou singular em zeros/decimais

Tags: gramática, números

É necessário pluralizar ou singularizar quando se usa o termo "zero"?

"Existe zero carro" ou "existem zero carros"?

---

E no uso de decimais?

"É 0,01 ponto percentual" ou "são 0,01 pontos percentuais"?

Comment: Creio que isto já foi perguntado [nesta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/n%C3%BAmeros-e-plural/1082#1082).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não sei em que tipo de situação alguém diria "zero carro(s)".**  Se eu tivesse que expressar a ausência de carros, eu diria que "não há nenhum carro" ou "não há carro algum", e acharia muito estranho alguém dizer que "existe zero carro na garagem".  Uma pesquisa rápida no Google mostrou "zero carro" como se referindo a carro zero quilômetro na maioria das vezes.  **Então tomemos como exemplo "zero quilômetro", um carro ainda sem uso.  Usamos o singular.**

> - Este carro é **zero quilômetro**.  É um **carro zero**.  É um **carro zerinho**.

o numeral "zero" qualificando um substantivo é de uso corrente nos seguintes termos:

> - zero hora
> - zero quilômetro
> - zero grau (temperatura)

E todos eles pedem um verbo no singular.

- "A temperatura ontem chegou a zero grau."
- "0,1 grau não faz diferença alguma."
- "Qualquer carro zero quilômetro serviria."

Portanto, se eu tiver que usar "zero carro" em uma frase, eu certamente usarei o verbo no singular.  Quanto ao uso de decimais, se usamos "**um ponto** percentual **é...**" no singular, ao invés de "**um pontos são**", não há motivo para que "0,1 ponto percentual" seja expresso no plural.

EDIT - **A resposta acima refere-se ao uso em pt-BR.**

**Em resposta ao comentário sobre a inexistência do termo "zero hora", explico que zero hora significa "meia-noite".  E é usado no singular.**

> - Podemos nos referir à meia-noite também como "zero hora". Como sempre devemos utilizar o plural para horas a partir de 2 ("às duas horas"; "às sete horas"; "às dez e meia"), podemos incorrer no erro de dizer/escrever "às zero hora" ou "às zero horas".  Mas cuidado: não há plural em "zero". Assim, diga e escreva: "à zero hora". [**Prof. Sérgio Duarte**](http://noticias.universia.com.br/destaque/especial/2011/08/02/852959/42/duvidas-e-dicas-portugues/duvidas-portugues-podemos-falar-zero-hora.html)

exemplos de "zero hora"

- ["O lançamento do foguete ocorreu à zero hora e dez minutos."](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=xx24DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT139&dq=%22%C3%A0+zero+hora%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibksmixrDPAhXOl5AKHRg7D48Q6AEINDAB#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20zero%20hora%22&f=false)
- ["A operação destinada a arrasar a cidade teve inicio à zero hora do dia 6 de agosto de 1945."](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=OOCSYWCKv4wC&pg=PA30&dq=%22%C3%A0+zero+hora%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibksmixrDPAhXOl5AKHRg7D48Q6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20zero%20hora%22&f=false)
- ["a contagem dos dias de ausência, para efeito da lavratura do termo de deserção, iniciarse-á à zero hora do dia seguinte àquele em que foi verificada a falta  injustificada do militar”](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=om8bBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA449&dq=%22%C3%A0+zero+hora%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibksmixrDPAhXOl5AKHRg7D48Q6AEIQDAD#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20zero%20hora%22&f=false)
- ["O melhor horário deverá ser sempre o das 21 horas à zero hora. Depois de zero hora não é aconselhável..."](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=DO5kwfSF2tEC&pg=PA356&dq=%22%C3%A0+zero+hora%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibksmixrDPAhXOl5AKHRg7D48Q6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20zero%20hora%22&f=false)

**Quanto a "zero grau", é usado por muitos.**  Quando a temperatura cai a "n graus abaixo de zero" ("grau" no singular se "n" for igual a 1) não se usa a palavra "grau" depois de zero. Em outras situações, podemos perfeitamente usar "zero grau". Veja os exemplos abaixo com seus respectivos links:

- ["já, no inverno o dia só tem 5 ou 6 horas de luz e a temperatura cai abaixo de zero grau."](http://buchadvocacia.com.br/exibeartigo.php?artigo_id=153)
- ["Nós temos impressões de fenômenos constantemente compartilhados – tal como o congelamento da água toda vez que a temperatura cai abaixo de zero grau ..."](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=FOAbBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT15&lpg=PT15&dq=%22a+temperatura+cai+abaixo+de+zero+grau.%22&source=bl&ots=tL2YLWXnqC&sig=B2zDlWFy2sSLp3zXgIDAWTVvxoA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrsNXZyrDPAhVEf5AKHafVAR0Q6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20temperatura%20cai%20abaixo%20de%20zero%20grau.%22&f=false)
- ["Mas este plano é aplicado apenas quando a temperatura cai abaixo de zero grau durante vários dias seguidos."](http://operamundi.uol.com.br/conteudo/entrevistas/41335/)
- ["Laminado com tecido de lã para sensação de aconchego mesmo onde a temperatura cai abaixo de zero grau centígrado."](https://portuguese.alibaba.com/product-detail/camo-hunting-gloves-168031940.html)
- ["Quando a temperatura cai abaixo de zero grau centígrado, a cerâmica se quebra com a expansão do gelo."](https://sergiogoes.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/09_05_29_ceramica-txy.pdf)
- ["A temperatura do solo nas vizinhanças dos eletrodos tem apreciável efeito
  sobre a resistividade, especialmente quando a temperatura cai abaixo de zero grau Celsius."](http://repositorio.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/11449/101906/caminhajr_ic_dr_botfca.pdf?sequence=1)

Comment: Estranho, em Portugal _zero horas/quilómetros/graus_ e _0,1 pontos percentuais_ (mas _uma décima percentual_).

Comment: Dizes «zero grau é muito frio» e presumo que «dois graus **é** muito frio» também.  Em francês também se recomenda *zéro franc*. Já em Portugal é *zero/0,1 graus*. Em inglês também, *zero/0.1 degrees*. Quando o zero e os decimais apareceram na nossa civilização, o singular e plural gramaticais já existiam há muito tempo e não estavam preparados para eles; pois singular era para 1, e plural para 2, 3, 4, etc. O zero e os decimais não se encaixavam naturalmente nem no singular nem no plural. Então o pessoal arranjou-se como pode. E o que tu fizeste for racionalizar ex-post a maneira como falas.

Comment: Obrigado pelo downvote (seja de onde tenha vindo), é sempre um incentivo para que a gente aperfeiçoe as respostas.  @Jacinto, sim, o exemplo  foi ruim porque "Cinco graus também é muito frio" ou seja, "a temperatura de cinco graus é muito fria.  Percebi isso em um outro exemplo que havia dado mas corrigi.  Corrijo também esse.

Comment: Tem uma explicação das diferenças nesse pdf [zero hora ou zero horas - Fatima Ribeiro](www.catedraportugues.uem.mz/lib/docs/ZERO%20HORAS_Final.pdf)

Comment: Realmente, mais complicado do que eu imaginei. Obrigado aos envolvidos.

Comment: Somente o numero 1 é singular, qualquer outro numero, incluindo 0 e fração, é plural. Os casos descritos nessa resposta são especiais, pois o zero nesse contexto não é quantitativo, em vez diso está atuando como um adjetivo. "Carro zero" é um carro novo que nunca foi dirigido, e não tem nada haver com uma quantidade de carros.

Comment: @Havenard  Minha resposta refere-se a pt-BR,  onde aprendemos que 0,1 miligrama, zero hora e zero grau são as formas corretas.  Quanto a "zero bananas", "zero pessoas", "zero livros", ninguém diz. Nem no singular e nem no plural.   Poderia então dar exemplos de frases onde "zero" é usado no plural?   E também 0,5.   Obrigado.

Comment: @AndréLyra   Minha resposta refere-se ao uso de "zero" no Brasil. O site citado por ti é de Moçambique, onde o uso é igual ao de Portugal.

Comment: @Centaurus Sim, eu me refiro a pt-BR. Somente 1 inteiro é singular. Também já vi quem use singular para frações como 0,1 ou 0,01, mas até onde sei isso não passa de um vício de linguagem. No entanto nunca ví ninguém usar 0 como singular, exceto em casos que já citei onde o "zero" em questão é um adjetivo. Por exemplo em sua respota, "zero grau" soa errado no Brasil, ninguém fala isso. É zero graus. "zero quilômetro" existe, mas só quando trata-se de adjetivar algo, dando sentido que aquilo (normalmente um carro) nunca foi usado.

Comment: @Centaurus Quanto a "zero hora", nunca ouvi. Se isso existe, deve tratar-se de alguma expressão, e não tem nada haver com quantidade de horas.

Comment: @Havenard  Seus dois comentários  " zero grau" soa errado no Brasil, ninguém fala isso."  e "Quanto a "zero hora", nunca ouvi. Se isso existe, deve tratar-se de alguma expressão, e não tem nada haver com quantidade de horas."  **Leia a minha resposta editada.**